# subtracting from Timestamp column

Tags: teradata

I am using below query to subtract 6 hours from a date stamp column - `ORDER_PLACED_TS`

```
select  (ORDER_PLACED_TS- interval '6' hour) AS NEW_TIME, SO.ORDER_PLACED_TS,SO.* from mytable SO
sample 10;
```

Above query returned expected results. Then, I tried replacing 6 with a column `Hour_Subtraction_column`  as below

```
select  (ORDER_PLACED_TS- interval Hour_Subtraction_column hour) AS NEW_TIME, SO.ORDER_PLACED_TS,SO.* from mytable SO
sample 10;
```

Error - `Expected something like a string or a unicode character betweeen the 'interval' keyword and the word 'Hour_Subtraction_column'`

Comment: What's the data type of `Hour_Subtraction_column`?

Comment: @dnoeth data type  is - INT

Answer (score 1):

Try `ORDER_PLACED_TS - (Hour_Subtraction_column * interval '1' hour)`.